# Two UITableView load in a view controller

Tags: iphone, tableview

Hello I've been stuck with a problem for some time. I am trying to load two `TableView` in a `ViewController`. I'm using customised `UITableViewCells` with nibs for one `UITableView` and I'm using normal `UITableViewCell` for another . Things are working when the `UITableView` with registered nibs is loaded but when the `UITableView` with non customised `TableViewCell` is loaded I`m getting the following error:

```
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

This is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView==tbl_search)
    {
        cell_intelisearch *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell =[[cell_intelisearch alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }

        [cell.btn_options addTarget:self action:@selector(add_Action_sheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;

    }
    //------FOR POP UP TABLE------
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";

        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell1==nil)
        {
            cell1 =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell1.textLabel.text=[arr_pop_up_status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell1;
    }
}
```

Any help will be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

In IB, for the non-custom table, make sure to paint a prototype cell.  In the attributes inspector, set it's style to one of the standard styles, and set it's identifier to `Cell1` to match the identifier you use in code.

Comment: thanks for the answer...but i should have mentioned is that i have made the non customised table by code..

Answer (score 0):

the below code for the non custom cell should be written in viewDidLoad or cellForRowAtIndexPath which may solve your problem

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```